# AWS IAM custom reusable action group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I was wondering if it is possible to create a reusable action in AWS. For example, I have the following policy for a role to use dynamo db

```
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
          "dynamodb:GetItem",
          "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
          "dynamodb:Query",
          "dynamodb:Scan",
          "dynamodb:PutItem",
          "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
          "dynamodb:DeleteItem"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "<my-dynamodb-arn-table>",
            "<my-othertable-arn>"
        ]
    }
]
```

Would it be possible to let's say group all those dynamo actions into some action group, let's call it `MyDynamoDbApplicationAction` and then use it like this

```
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "MyDynamoDbApplicationAction"              
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "<my-dynamodb-arn-table>",
            "<my-othertable-arn>"
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible in raw IAM Policies.

You could, of course, write your own code to substitute values and create policies.

Comment: Can you expand on my own code part? Like do a string replace of `MyDynamoDbApplicationAction` with all the dynamo permissions, or something else?

Comment: There is an API call to store policies. You could write code that reads a local file, performs substitutions, then sends the result to AWS. Basically, it would all happen _before_ the policy is sent to AWS.